# Cannot order multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
array(40) {
  [134114]=>
  array(5) {
    ["yeniPoz"]=>
    int(3)
    ["yeniPuan"]=>
    int(108)
    ["isim"]=>
    string(16) "PERSON A"
    ["eskiPoz"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["eskiPuan"]=>
    string(3) "102"
  }
  [307674]=>
  array(5) {
    ["yeniPoz"]=>
    int(2)
    ["yeniPuan"]=>
    int(83)
    ["isim"]=>
    string(16) "PERSON B"
    ["eskiPoz"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["eskiPuan"]=>
    string(2) "75"
  }
  [263724]=>
  array(5) {
    ["yeniPoz"]=>
    int(10)
    ["yeniPuan"]=>
    int(65)
    ["isim"]=>
    string(9) "PERSON C"
    ["eskiPoz"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["eskiPuan"]=>
    string(2) "65"
  }

[209310]=>
  array(5) {
    ["yeniPoz"]=>
    int(1)
    ["yeniPuan"]=>
    int(72)
    ["isim"]=>
    string(29) "PERSON D"
    ["eskiPoz"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["eskiPuan"]=>
    string(2) "62"
  }
...
```

This array public element of a class (`public $datas`) . 
I want to order this array with **yeniPuan** .

```
function orderManagersFunc($a, $b)
{
    return $b['yeniPuan'] - $a['yeniPuan'];
}

function orderManager()
{
    uasort($this->datas, "orderManagersFunc");
}
```

Result should be like this :

1. PERSON A
2. PERSON B
3. PERSON D
4. PERSON C

But result :

1. PERSON A
2. PERSON B
3. PERSON C
4. PERSON D

I think it's ordering by ["eskiPuan"] .

But i don't know, why?

---

If you need all codes, you can check this repo : https://github.com/erayalakese/GPRO-live-standings

Class in GLS.class.php file. And i'm calling functions from index.php

Comment: I suppose suggesting you use objects instead of deep associate arrays like this is some advice that is too late? You could almost certainly create an object or objects that would make this work so much easier for yourself.

Comment: @thatidiotguy , Maybe a little example ? It's (should be) easier ordering arrays . Can you give me a little example?

Comment: The arrays all have the same inner array with the same object keys. This reeks of a class with those keys as the name of the variables in the class. Then when you order stuff, you are simply ordering according to the field of one object which you would easily do with a insertion sort.

Comment: @thatidiotguy , oh , it's mean , i have to change a lots of thing. I will try it, if i couldn't find a quicker way. Thank you. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to replace your following line:

```
uasort($this->datas, "orderManagersFunc");
```

for this one:

```
uasort($this->datas, array($this,"orderManagersFunc"));
```

as that is the correct syntax to indicate that you want to sort by a method in your class.

Comment: THis script calculating season positions for a online race game. And recently there is a race. Because of this, i can't try anything (datas changing every second) . I'll try after race (tomorrow) and give you a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `array_multisort` I've used this for multidimensional arrays like yours. I had to build an array of the values I wanted to sort by using a loop through the multidimensional array first. Then you can sort by using that array in array_multisort. Something like this. I think `usort` will also work

```
foreach($haystack as $key => $row){
    $arrayOfValuesToSortBy[$key] = $row['keyToSortBy']];
}

array_multisort($arrayOfValuesToSortBy, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $haystack);
```

Comment: I was using multisort but in my past question (deleted because of duplicate question) they suggest me **uasort** instead of multisort . And actually, that was solved my problem. And than it's suddenşy stopped working. I think it's because of variable types (integer or string) . Notice, ["eskiPuan"] is string.

Comment: THis script calculating season positions for a online race game. And recently there is a race. Because of this, i can't try anything (datas changing every second) . I'll try after race (tomorrow) and give you a comment.

Answer (score 0):

--- EDIT ---

You need to use:

```
uasort($this->datas, "GLS::orderManagersFunc");
```

OR (as suggested by Nelson; tested that one too... It's working too):

```
uasort($this->datas, array($this, "orderManagersFunc"));
```

The user order function is correctly referenced by "GLS::orderManagersFunc" not just "orderManagersFunc" (which should output a warning). This is why your result was not ordered by 'yeniPuan' and stayed as is.

Comment: Very strange you suggested your last syntax in your second edit and after my answer appeared.

Comment: @Nelson: right my first edit was just the first variation. I took over your variation, after I just tested it in my code (gave you an up-vote by the way) - so it's just confirmed to work correctly.

Comment: Added some credits for your code; I remember to have seen the array($this, "methodname")-Variation in the manual pages -- Seems the better solution to me, as the class name possibly changes.

Comment: THis script calculating season positions for a online race game. And recently there is a race. Because of this, i can't try anything (datas changing every second) . I'll try after race (tomorrow) and give you a comment.